# Execute C# console application(.exe) using .bat file

Tags: c#, batch-file

I wrote a C# Console Application which takes one argument. The application  runs successfully with visual studio. After build/re-build, I have copied the bin/debug directory contents into c:\batch folder (deployed) I want to run the exe from this directory using a bat file which I created in the c:\batch folder. But it is not running. I tried the following in bat file

```
1) start /d "c:\batch" myapp.exe arg1
2) start /d "" myapp.exe arg1
3) myapp.exe arg1
```

I was not able to run this using task scheduler 
when I run this through cmd it says start not recognized.
What else am I missing?

Comment: Is your batch file called with the right working directory? If you put a cd (http://www.computerhope.com/cdhlp.htm) in your batch file, before calling the app name (without start) does it work?

Comment: You might be missing start.exe in C:\windows

Comment: @Novice, there is no start.exe.  START is an internal command to CMD.exe.

Comment: Well I don't know if I am 100% right but every common command in CMD is actually a binary sitting in %windir ie. C:\windows in your case ; eg. net,ping,netstat etc.Again just my opinion :)

Comment: tried with cd. not working.

Comment: Not all cd is very simple functionality but for special task binary is there try ping.exe

Comment: The command not found is error is either your exe not found or may be environment path is not registered in system properties so try search start.exe in your drive and add(append with;) it's path in environment variable named `path`.

Comment: @Novice, this is not a place for opinions.  Code is black and white. True or False.  Please read this link.  It is a listing of all the internal commands for CMD.EXE shell. Start is an internal command. Not a separate executable. http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html

Comment: @Squashman yeh got it and thanx for this site it's like wikipedia of windows commands.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use the debug Version.
You need to build a "Release Version". (Click the dropdown button where debug is located)
This will then be located in the release folder.

also use ["START"](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

Comment: A debug version should still launch from a batch file without a problem.

Comment: @FrancisLord It should still not be used as release.

Comment: I agree, however this would not fix OP's issue.

Also, he might still be debugging his app, where a debug version is not a problem (albeit no much more useful for debugging than a release version)

Comment: @FrancisLord This is why i posted the link to the documentation for "START" not start as in the OP´s Q.

Comment: START /D "C:\batchFiles" myapp.exe arg1 was not working too

Comment: Should I set any environment variables? I am trying to execute it through cmd promt with c:\

Comment: @AVSSM try start "" "c:\batch\myapp.exe" param1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120613/discussion-between-gismo-and-avssm).